# Emacs Key-binding and the TERM variable

Tags: terminal, emacs, gnu-screen, colors

I changed the value of `TERM` to `screen-256color` from `xterm` and it effects the key-bindings in Emacs. Mainly the bindings that use the arrow keys now inserts `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` instead of running `backward-word` and `forward-word` ect. How should I set up 256 colors without affecting the key-bindings.

Comment: Have you tried `xterm-color` for your `TERM`? most modern termcap/curses have the 256-color variant

Comment: `xterm-color` doesn't seem to do the trick. Seems `screen-256color` is needed for [powerline](https://github.com/erikw/tmux-powerline)

Comment: Sorry, that should of been `TERM=xterm-256color` :)

Comment: `xterm-256color` does the trick although the choice of colors emacs uses for syntax highlighting isn't as appealing.

Answer (score 2):

Terminals only understand characters, not keys, so keys that are not printable characters are encoded as control characters or escape sequences.

Different terminals send different escape sequences for some keys. Fortunately, there's no conflict on common terminals: you can [declare the escape sequences](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) without worrying about which terminal you're on.

Use `C-c h` or `C-q` followed by the function key to see what escape sequence it sends.

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\eOA" [up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\eOB" [down])
(define-key input-decode-map "\eOC" [left])
(define-key input-decode-map "\eOD" [right])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[A" [up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[B" [down])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[C" [left])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[D" [right])
```